# can we select columns which starts with particular string in ADF Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So I have a data and I have to select columns which starts with "Rain" using dataflow.
Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: Can you please provide all the column names of the data you are using?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT Column names are something like these!
Date , Rainfall_Gallicano , Rainfall_Pontetetto , Rainfall_Monte_Serra , Rainfall_Orentano
Rainfall_Borgo_a_Mozzano , Depth_to_Groundwater_LT2 , Depth_to_Groundwater_SAL , Depth_to_Groundwater_PAG , Depth_to_Groundwater_CoS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `select` transformations. The following is a demonstration of how you can achieve this.

- The following are the columns taken as a the source.

[image]

- After adding the source, use `select transformation`. In this, remove all the mapped columns. Click on `Add Mapping -> Rule-based Mapping`

[image]

- In this rule-based mapping, you can use the condition to select the column names starting with `Rain`. The rule is `startsWith(name,'Rain')` and the output column name is `$$` (indicates the same name as source column name)

[image]

- You can inspect the output where you can see that only column with name starting with `Rain` are selected.

[image]

Comment: Please note that the original question contains no details: no effort, no specific issue; just a request for "how to do it." You shouldn't be answering such questions - just ask the OP to provide the work they've done. Otherwise, you're providing free consulting services, and that's not the intent of this site.